# BarcodeFormat.h file not found in zxing api in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, zxing

Integrate Zxing API in my project. Most of errors remove from api but this error not remove and there is no guidence available on net. what can I do for removing this error.[image]

Comment: in which file the error is happening ? And is the file is in same project or different project

Answer (score 0):

Compiler expects this header file in your current directory where your project is kept.

If it is not there give it absolute path inside < >, as we do for frameworks, like

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
```